# Django Template - Where is it coded to look for this specific template?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have `chrono/chrono/templates/requests_app/request_list.html` which gets loaded when `url(r'^$', BookListView.as_view())`, gets hit. `BookListView.as_view()` is `class BookListView(ListView): model = Request`. When in Django is it being told to look for `chrono/chrono/templates/requests_app/request_list.html`?

For instance, I can change the name `request_list.html` to `foo_request_list.html` and it will say error `request_list.html` not found. So I am trying to find where it is coded to look for request_list.html. I looked in settings/base.py and there was no mention of request_list.html.

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.views.generic import TemplateView, ListView
from requests_app.views import BookListView
from django.contrib.auth.views import login

from requests_app.forms import LoginForm

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
   # url(r'^$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='base.html')),
    url(r'^$', BookListView.as_view()),
    url(r'^login/$', login, {'authentication_form': LoginForm}, name='login'),

    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'chrono.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^chrono/', include('chrono.foo.urls')),

    # Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
    # url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)

from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView, RedirectView
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.generic import ListView
from requests_app.models import Request, Region
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

class BookListView(ListView):
    model = Request
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens somewhere in code that is included by the import of `django.views.generic.ListView`. In `generic/list.py`, `MultipleObjectTemplateResponseMixin` is where the filename is finally put together.

The code builds the template like so

- Folder prefix is the app name that this `ListView` is in
- The part before `_list.html` is inferred by checking `model.__name__`, which is `Request.__name__` in your example and will be Request by default and then lowercasing that.
- `_list` is specified by `ListView`
- `.html` is in `MultipleObjectTemplateResponseMixin`

If you don't like the file name it is giving you and you want to keep your app name as well as the name of the class you are specifying as your model you can override the above behavior in your `BookListView`

```
class BookListView(ListView):
    model = Request
    template_name = "books/foo_request_list.html"
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#viewing-subsets-of-objects
This section deals with other things but they show overriding the template name in their example.

Comment: Without specifying it, where is it coded to look for request_list.html? I f I rename request_list.html it will error out because it is specifically looking for request_list.html.

Comment: It is in the generic module you are importing. in generic/list.py there is a method called MultipleObjectTemplateResponseMixin that puts the file name together

Comment: It uses the name Request because the name of your model is Request

Comment: How did request_list.html get in django.views.generic since I never specified it?

Comment: It is getting the result of model.__name__ which will be 'Request' and then lowercasing that and appending _list.html